# JPA Criteria - fetch with where clause

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

I have following query which is working fine:

```
public ContractorContractor findContractorByName(String contractorName) {
   CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
   CriteriaQuery<ContractorContractor> query = builder.createQuery(ContractorContractor.class);
   Root<ContractorContractor> root = query.from(ContractorContractor.class);
   query.select(root).distinct(true);

   Predicate namePredicate = builder.like(root.get(ContractorContractor_.name), contractorName);
   query.where(builder.and(namePredicate));

   return em.createQuery(query).getSingleResult();
}
```

Above query gives me single contractor by name or throws exception.
Now I would like to do same thing but get more informations about contractor (add the fetch to another child of contractor) but with following query I do not get result (org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: No result found for query is thrown). Query with fetch:

```
public ContractorContractor findContractorByName(String contractorName) {
   CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
   CriteriaQuery<ContractorContractor> query = builder.createQuery(ContractorContractor.class);
   Root<ContractorContractor> root = query.from(ContractorContractor.class);
   root.fetch(ContractorContractor_.countries);
   query.select(root).distinct(true);

   Predicate namePredicate = builder.like(root.get(ContractorContractor_.name), contractorName);
   query.where(builder.and(namePredicate));

   return em.createQuery(query).getSingleResult();
}
```

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong and why in above query?

Comment: what SQL is GENERATED by the JPA provider? look in its log. This is a step called "debugging"

Comment: http://pastebin.com/c1QYb6TY  there is quite a lot of columns but..

Comment: so execute the SQL yourself MANUALLY in the datastore

Comment: Have you tried with `root.fetch(ContractorContractor_.countries, JoinType.LEFT);`?

Comment: Sorry about my previous comment but I checked it on wrong spring profile :) It works! Thank You very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you have accidentally limited the domain of your query by adding a *inner fetch join* with the addition of the following statement:

```
root.fetch(ContractorContractor_.countries);
```

As per JPA 2.1, JSR 338, section 6.5.4

> [...] A fetch join has the **same join semantics** as the corresponding inner or outer join [...]

Thus changing the implicit *inner fetch join* (`JoinType.INNER`) to an *(outer) left fetch join* should solve your problem:

```
root.fetch(ContractorContractor_.countries, JoinType.LEFT);
```

This side effect might seem a little unexpected which is probably why the authors of the specification added the following comment (although in context with standard joins, section 4.4.7):

> Application  developers  should  use  caution  in  defining  identification  variables  **because  the  domain  of  the query can depend on whether there are any values** of the declared type.